# "git fetch" doesn't update commit history in "git log"

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log, git-fetch

I'm new to git workflow and was following a tutorial online about "git fetch". Here are the performed steps:

1. "git pull" to synchronize files and history from remote repo
2. A new commit was performed by the **same user** **online**
3. "git remote show origin" show that local branch is "out of date" with remote repo
4. "git fetch" was performed to synchronize metadata and not local files

For the tutorial  -->  After "git fetch" when "git log" is used to view commit history, it shows the last performed commit and who did it

For me -->  After "git fetch" when "git log" is used, it **doesn't show me the last performed commit**

I tried "git pull" and then both commit history and local file got updated. **Am I doing something wrong here (or) "git fetch" isn't supposed to update the log history**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have synchronized data with remote, but not change your head commit, so if you want to check remote commit log you should use `git log origin/master` where `origin` is remote name and `master` is name of branch that you want to show.
If you want change yours commit to the latest from remote you should use `git pull` instead `git fetch`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *also* do either a `git pull`, or merge the remote tracking branch with you local branch.  Assuming your local branch were named `local`, you could either do:

```
# from local
git pull origin local
```

or

```
# from local
git fetch origin
git merge origin/local
```

The problem with only doing a `git fetch` is that it updates the remote tracking (local) branch `origin/local`, but does *not* actually do anything to your `local` branch.  To update `local` with the latest work, you need to `git pull` (the first option), which does a merge with `origin/local`, or just do an explicit merge with `origin/local` (the second option).

Comment: I have a small doubt here. When you perform a "git pull" as mentioned above (if remote is ahead by a commit), What happens to my local edited file ? Will I retain the changes (or) would the remote file be replacing my local file ?

Comment: It depends.  In earlier versions of Git, you could never do this, and you would get a warning that your local changes would be overwritten.  In later versions of Git, sometimes a pull is possible, sometimes not.  Best practice to always have a clean working directory/stage when doing a `git pull`.

Comment: I just found out that "local changes are never overwritten" in case of "git pull". The Overwriting happens only when the git status is cleared and has no merge conflicts. In cases where new commits in Online Repo ( say new file addition (or) file changes ) that doesn't conflict with last commit in local, the local changes are always retained and in case of any conflicts, it doesn't allow us to perform "git pull". Thanks for your help